# Accessing ec2 instance via ftp/ssh from user other than ec2-user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ftp

I've created a key-pair and have access to a linux instance via FTP and SSH using ec2-user. I have also added the desired user to all groups that ec2-user is in. All of this was tested using the .ppk key, generated my puttygen, which allowed ec2-user to the instance. I even changed the key type from SSH-2 to SSH-1 via puttygen.

I've followed countless guides, but without any luck. Is there anything else I can do?

From what I've read I'll have to create a key-pair (dont know where) for each user, and add one of the keys to a .ssh directory.

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: same issue has been asked countless time.  this is one of those solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701395/how-do-i-configure-multiple-ssh-access-to-an-ec2-instance?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming putty and AWS EC2

Step by step

1) AWS EC2 must be running sshd and have port 22 open on security groups.  If you can login with the default user then this is ok with other users from the same address

2) generate a putty key pair using putty keygen.   During the setup process you will be offered a "public key for pasting".  Copy this into your cut n paste buffer
Also save the private part of the key

3) login to the AWS EC2 and become root.

4) If you haven't made the user (let's call the user "binky") make it with adduser or a similar command

5) issue commands like this to add key

```
cd ~binky
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
cat > authorized_keys
```

paste the public key from step 2 here and press ctrl-D

nb use the command `wc -l authorized_keys` to check that your cut n paste is one line only.  The file has one line per key

6) ensure that file permissions are correct

```
cd ~binky
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R binky .ssh
```

7) back on your putty host run pageant.  Right click on the hat logo in the tray/bar thing (I'm not an MS Windows expert) and use "add key" to add the private key from step 2

8) on your putty host open a new, blank connection.  Give the ip or domain name in the "Host Name (or IP Address)" box.  In the left hand menu tree find the "connection" -> "data" box and give the "auto login username" as the user on EC2 (binky)

9) save the settings under a new name using the "session" box of putty

10) click on "open" and you should be logged on

Comment: This makes more sense. I really appreciate your answer.   I was assuming a key pair was needed for each user I needed, and so I went about my problem doing more than I needed.

Comment: If you use the same key pair for each user then if someone has that key pair they can login as as that user.  Usually each person has their own unique key and they would use that to access different "user accounts" on remote servers